# Adding an unused column creates an error in JoinAcross

Tags: associations

I'd been having trouble using [`JoinAcross`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinAcross.html) on two datasets.  After going through the answers to my original question and fixing my code, I find I'm now having a problem that I think is being caused by my data.  I'm adding a column to an Excel sheet, but not using it in my dataset.  I'm reading in two Excel sheets, "Reported" and "Estimated".  Below are screens shot of "Reported" followed by "Estimated":

[image: Reported]

[image: Estimated]

Next is my code and its output:

```
repFile = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Reported"}];
repHeader = repFile[[1]];
repData = repFile[[2 ;;]];

estFile = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Estimated"}];
estHeader = estFile[[1]];
estData = estFile[[2 ;;]];

repDS = Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[repHeader, #] &]@repData;
estDS = Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[estHeader, #] &]@estData;

rep1 = repDS[All, {"a", "z1"}];
est1 = estDS[All, {"a", "z2"}];

rep1
est1
rep1 // Normal
est1 // Normal
JoinAcross[rep1, est1, "a"]
```

[image: Output1]

Now I add one column to "Estimated" to get:

[image: Estimated2]

My output now looks like:

[image: Output2]

Since I'm not actually bringing in that additional column to the dataset I don't understand what's happening.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `JoinAcross` doesn't take `Dataset` arguments, which is what  your 2nd example suggests. `Normal`'ize.

Comment: @alancalvitti - I thought it was supposed to work with Datasets also.  However you're probably right.  If I re-code and use Assocations I don't get the error.

Comment: @alancalvitti - JoinAcross does take dataset as an argument - though possibly with some caveats.  See [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56902/join-two-datasets-on-keys)