# Quotes vs No Quotes for Association Keys

Tags: associations

I've tended to not put quotes around the names of my `Key` when making `Associations`.  For example:

```
devToaAssoc = AssociationThread[{Flag, ALOB, LI}, {True, #[[1]], #[[3 ;; 12]]}] & /@ dataIn;
```

However I've run into problems in trying to do certain things.  For example, in the `Dataset` section of Help, there is the following example:

```
dataset[Select[#a < 5 &]]
```

If I change the example so that the key is a, but without quotes, I can't get a `Select` to work.  I've tried a number of things, for example, using `Key[a]`, and without the &.  Also I've noticed that the `Dataset` display is quite different if I remove the quotes from the `Key` A.

I have 2 questions.  First, is there some way I should be able to get that `Select` statement to work if my key doesn't have quotes?  Second, are there any other issues I should be aware of that might make NOT using quotes a bad idea?

Comment: Try `dataset[Select[Key[a] < 5 &]] `

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go so far as to call using symbols as keys a bad idea, but I get the sense from all the various examples in the docs on the use of associations that Wolfram is encouraging us to use string keys rather symbol keys.

Comment: @m_goldberg  I tried your example and I wind up with what appears to be an empty result.  It says 0 rows and doesn't show anything.  I also see that most, but not all, of the examples use string keys.  I also don't know what would happen if I were to use one of those symbols elsewhere.  Probably nothing good.

Comment: Since you didn't provide a means for me to build `dataset`, it's impossible for me to investigate what went wrong with `dataset[Select[Key[a] < 5 &]]`. You need to provide real data if you want more than vague advice.

Comment: @m_goldberg - I used the example in Help.  I tried SquareOne's suggestion and it did work - although I thought I had tried that one before.  I appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that the string quoted keys behaviour is has changed over the 10.0.x and 10.x releases

Comment: @GordonCoale I didn't know that.  Can you point me to information on those changes?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56902/join-two-datasets-on-keys/56943#comment163362_56943).  That was on 10.0 as I recall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

Given for example

```
dataset = Dataset[{
    <|AZ -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
    <|AZ -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>}];
```

then

```
dataset[Select[#[AZ] > 1 &], "b"]
```

returns

[image]