# JoinAcross for large Datasets

Tags: dataset, associations

When running JoinAcross for larger datasets (lists of associations, ~100k lines, >100 columns) in Mathematica 10.1 I get the following behaviour:

```
mergeddata=JoinAcross[dataset1,dataset2,"c1"]
```

generates output of the form

```
{<|c1->*value1*,c2->Empty,c3->*value2*,...|>,...}
```

I can't seem to find a way to view this output or any queries on mergeddata in the standard tabular format for datasets, which works fine for dataset1 and dataset2.

According to the answers in

[Join two datasets on keys](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56902/join-two-datasets-on-keys)

this should work without a problem.

Column "c1" in my dataset1 contains values which do not occur in dataset2, and vice versa. Apart from that, there seems to be nothing special about both datasets.

Comment: `{<|c1->*value1*,c2->Empty,c3->*value2*,...|>,...}` here `c1` is an `Expression` and not a `String` - for your join you specify `"c1"` which doesn't look like a key in your `Datasets`